Can we remove "not reproducible" from off-topic reasons in the Staging Ground?
When a question in the Staging Ground lacks details for reproducing the issue, it should be marked as "Requires Major Changes" instead of being closed as off-topic.
The close reason "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" seems to contradict that goal. Would it be possible to change that close reason to only include typos?

A typo question does not need "major changes", it's simply a typo and should still be closed. It seems that when a question "lacks details for reproducing an issue" it should generally be closed as "needs debugging details", not as "not reproducible". "Not reproducible" should for when the details are there, but the outcome that the question posits cannot be reproduced. Not posting this as an answer since I don't use SG, and not sure what "require major changes" entails.

@yivi I meant that the typo close reason should stay in the Staging Ground. And there is no Needs debugging details close reason because questions like that should be marked as Requires Major changes (like anything that requires clarification by the author like a missing MCVE).

"Why is b equal to 5 after adding one and one and assigning the result to b:  b = 1 + 1; print b;" is not a typo, but clearly not reproducible either, there is no useful question to uncover by adding more detail either. It's simply "Not reproducible" so should be closed as such, no matter wether it's in the SG or not.

The important part of "Typo or not reproducible" is in the details: it's meant for cases where the problem is not useful in the future. It's not supposed to only be used for typos. In fact, some typos should better have a canonical duplicate. Trivial thing like usre vs user are an example of not useful, though. The "cannot reproduce" part is the same - it's not meant to be "provide a MCVE" (which is indeed "Needs debugging details") it's for situations like "why 2 + 2 == 5" or even solved questions but the cause/solution is not clear (worked a day later). When it won't help others

Related non-staging-ground question. It seems to me the problem is that people misunderstand what "not reproducible" means. It should be reserved for questions that are fundamentally not reproducible, rather than for ones that are just lacking necessary details.

@JohnMontgomery The Staging Ground doesn't have a needs debugging details close reason so typo/nonreproducable is the closest-looking close reason they have. This is very easy to confuse, especially since the Staging Ground is available with 500+ reputation including closing.

When a question "lacks details for reproducing the issue", that means that the issue could be reproduced if those details were provided. That is not what the "typo or not reproducible" closure reason is for. That's what the "needs debugging details" closure reason is for, on the main site. Which is why both those reasons exist separately.
Similarly, if someone is asking the OP to provide debugging details, that entails a belief that the problem was not caused by a simple typo or an idiosyncratic logic error, but that the problem was caused by some non-obvious fault that needs to be debugged or by a genuine conceptual misunderstanding.
The purpose of the "typo or not reproducible" closure reason is to indicate that the problem with the question cannot be fixed, because either:

There is no actual question since the code works when properly typed in

The "missing information" does not exist, as the problem cannot be reproduced, and thus that information cannot be supplied.


As such, it would be simply incorrect to mark these questions as requiring major changes; they don't require changes, because changes can't help, and they should be closed and deleted, because there is no way to make them useful without fundamentally changing the question.
Related:

How do we deal with misuse of "typo/no longer reproducible" close-reason?

When is it acceptable to delete a post?

Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance

Closing as a mental typo


